# System crontab won't run for certain user on Centos 7

Tags: centos, cron, crontab

I have a super simple system crontab to run as a specific user. For a user that can login to a Gnome session it works fine. For another user that I use just for system tasks, it will not run.

This is a CentOS 7 box that shows `systemctl status crond` as running.

To debug the situation I have reduced the file `/etc/cron.d/test` to:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * etluser /bin/echo "-- trying" >> /tmp/auto_services.txt
```

With the user **etluser** nothing runs. The tmp file does not appear. There is no output in `journalctl -xe`, no `/var/log/cron` entry and no email to root.

```
$ getent group etluser
etluser:x:499:otheruser

$ getent passwd etluser
etluser:x:600:499::/home/etluser:/bin/bash

$ getent shadow
etluser:$6$mw...../:18429:0:90:7:::
```

Also `/etc/cron.deny` is empty and `/etc/cron.allow` is not present.

If I change the user in the cron.d file to my standard login user **otheruser** then the job runs fine.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * otheruser /bin/echo "-- trying" >> /tmp/auto_services.txt
```

`/etc/pam.d/crond` shows

```
account    include    system-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    system-auth
auth       include    system-auth
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the job won't run if the password of the user has expired. I wouldn't normally know this has happened as I just `sudo -u etluser -i` to work as that user, and that doesn't fail.

Resetting the password did the trick. Now I just need to set a dummy password and set the expiration time to a lifetime.